# Front Controller (app.php) called multiple times for 1 request

Tags: php, symfony, front-controller

Here is my issue.

**Situation**

I am debugging symfony2 application (having some issues with posted data). On this occasion, i checked how many times app.php vs app_dev.php are called when handling a request.

example:
request (from browser) : /demo/display/foos

logger in app.php (resp. app_dev.php):

```
//logger function 
function logtxt($logtxt, $name='myLog'){
  $fp = fopen($name.'.txt','a+');
  fseek($fp,SEEK_END);
  $newLog=date('H:i:s', time()).' - '.':'."\r\n".$logtxt."\r\n".'--------------------------------------------';
  fputs($fp,$newLog);
  fclose($fp); //basta
}

//logger call
logtxt('in app_dev.php ('.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'].')');
```

it basically adds a line in a logfile each time logtxt is called.

**Issue**

It appears that, in my applications, app_dev.php is called multiple times for a single request (mostly 2 times or 3 times). I tried with an empty project: app.php or app_dev.php are called only on time at each request.

I was thinking of redirections I would be doing, but this is not always the case. More amazing, there is sometimes a difference between app.php log count and app_dev.php log count for a same request!

I do not understand why the front-controller should be called more than once in a request. Also, it seems that it has some impact in production. For instance, in an old project, $_POST gets reset between these calls and its data seem to get lost (!).

for instance, for 1 same request, I will have in dev and prod envs:

```
15:45:51 - in app_dev.php:
in app_dev.php ($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})

15:45:51 - in foo Controller:
fooControllerAction called ($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})
--------------------------------------------
15:45:52 - in app_dev.php:
in app_dev.php ($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
```

whereas with app.php log:

```
15:44:07 - in app.php:
in app.php ($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})

--------------------------------------------
15:44:07 - in app.php:
in app.php ($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
15:44:07 - in fooController:
fooControllerAction called ($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
```

Consequence:
posted variable are usable by controller in dev environment, but not in prod environment, for the same request:

**Solution**

Is this behaviour known to someone ? I am eager to understand background justifying this, and check that it doesn't lead to errors. Also, if this is due to bad dev practice, I would change mine.

Thanks a lot in advance for sharing your wisdom!

Cheers,

Comment: I think the difference between `app_dev` and `app` is due to multiple call to debug toolbar and application. As for the `app` itself, does you app contain `http` subrequest? That could explain multiple calls...

Comment: How do you invoke this method? In you `app.php`/`app_dev.php`? If so, I would suggest setting up kernel listener instead and then probing the request for type (subrequest/top-level request) and log only those that you want....

Comment: Hi jperovic, thanks for your feedback. Interesting thought concerning calls to debug toolbar. I do invoke this method in app.php/ app_dev.php. I am not precisely sure yet how to set up the said listener, but may have a look at it.

Comment: Hey @Wisebes! I have added the answer with some links on how to create kernel listeners :)

Comment: I'd recommend Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting kernel listener see this page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

... specifically this section which covers request listener:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types

You have here an example on how to detect if request is `subrequest` or `master` ;)

When you have detected `HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST` as your request type you could apply the same logic you have shown in your question...

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look a this immediately. Also, good call concerning difference in log count between app.php and app_dev : due to profiling subrequests. I edited my question a bit though, some of the mystery remains. This is helpful anyway.

Comment: Nice method. However, trying it with same logic as above in a new project, i still get MASTER_REQUEST called twice in dev environment and only once in prod environment :/

Comment: Go into config_dev.yml and turn the toolbar off.  I suspect the second request will go away.

Comment: Excellent guess. so now I understand much better these multiple requests. At last, only the issue described remains (as edited) : it seems that the request caught by kernel gets screwed up just before being given to controller... main matter described is now solved now however. this will be in another thread.