# Posted variables lost while handling request

Tags: symfony, post, request

I am currently facing the following issue: posted data of the request seem to get cleared at some point.

**Situation:**

in a sf2 application, I have a custom form at "/foo". it posts 2 properties: `{"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"}`

**Issue:**

the controller supposed to handle this works perfectly well in dev env, but doesn't work in PROD environment. Investigation shows that it is due to lack of posted data. Therefore, I did 2 methodology of logs, based on the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761383/front-controller-app-php-called-multiple-times-for-1-request).

1) log via kernel listener.
I have a `Library::logtxt('text')` function that writes one line with 'text' in a log file each time it is called. I put it in the controller handling the request.

in a Kernel Listener, I have the following method:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
        // don't do anything if it's not the master request
        return;
    }
    //this is master request: do something.
    Library::logtxt('($post: '.json_encode($_POST).')');

}
```

calling it on respectively with app_dev.php and app.php, I get: 
log from web/app_dev.php:

```
16:42:28 - Acme\DemoBundle\RequestListener:
($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})
--------------------------------------------
16:42:28 - Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\FooController:
fooControllerAction called ($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})
```

log from web/app.php:

```
16:42:28 - Acme\DemoBundle\RequestListener:
($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
16:42:28 - Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\FooController:
fooControllerAction called ($post: [])
```

2) To be sure that posted data are indeed sent, I but the Library::logtxt('') logger in web/app.php. I get:
app.php:

```
16:44:07 - :
in app.php ($post: {"sort":"sort","property":"barcode"})
--------------------------------------------
16:44:07 - :
in app.php ($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
16:44:07 - Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\FooController:
fooControllerAction called ($post: [])
--------------------------------------------
```

**Solution**

This all seems to indicate that something happens in production that "destroys" posted data. Would Someone know what is at stake here?

EDIT:
the difference seems to be du to config_dev.yml.

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

when this is commented app_dev.php get screwed the same way as app.php. if not, app_dev.php works...

Thanks a lot in advance for caring

Regards,

---

**EDITS:**

app/config/routing.yml

```
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /connect


#FOS : 
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google

acme_user:
    resource: "@AcmeUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

acme_a:
    resource: "@AcmeABundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

acme_another:
    resource: "@AcmeAnotherBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /another/
```

app/config/routing_dev.yml:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_console:
    resource: "@CoreSphereConsoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /_console

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Request` object instead of the `$_POST`:

```
Library::logtxt('($post: ' . $event->getRequest()->request->all() . ')');
```

Do you get an empty array here as well?

Comment: sadly yes. request->post: []. this seems to be bound to the 'framework' settings in config_dev. if I comment it, app_dev.php does not work any more either...

Answer (score 0):

You should check `app/logs/prod.log` for any issues.

You should also run `app/console --env=prod cache:clear` to be on the safe side.

As mentioned [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes), you should make use of `php app/console router:debug` to check if all your routes are configured properly.

If none of these helped, Please post your `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml`. My guess is that this is a routing problem that internally redirect your request and loses the `post` information in the middle.